# UID for access control

Tags: authentication, nfc, uniqueidentifier, access-control, mifare

I am using Mifare Ultralight C to make a access control system. 
The method I am using is based on the UID of the card. 
I can read the UID by NFC Reader (SeeedStudio shield on Arduino UNO) 
However, the UID is not reliable since there are writable UID card out there in the market. So I think that I should secure the connection by 3DES authentication and then block the reading from 0x00 which is from the first serial number byte. 
Is it the correct way to implement access control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot block read access to the UID. The UID is an immanent part of the anticollision/tag enumeration phase of ISO 14443 so the tag will always reveal that information. Moreover, Ultralight C permits read/write protection only from page 3 to the end of the memory.

What you could do is the following:

1. Use the UID to identify the tag.
2. Derive a tag-specific key based on a master key and the tag's UID.

   K<sub>tag</sub> = f<sub>key_derivation</sub>(UID<sub>tag</sub>, K<sub>master</sub>)
3. Use that key K<sub>tag</sub> as 3DES key for the Ultralight C authentication.
4. Protect (read and write) the whole data memory of the tag.
5. Possibly store some additional authentication information on the tag (e.g. a signature over the UID). However, you should keep in mind that after authentication read operations are neither encrypted nor integrity protected. This means that an attacker could potentially retrieve the data stored on a tag by listening into the communication between a legit tag and a legit reader. Moreover, an attacker might be able to authenticate with a legit tag and then intercept any further read commands to return manipulated data. Basically this means that you should refrain from storing any non-integrity-protected permission information on such a tag.

*And finally: MIFARE Ultralight C is certainly not meant to be used for access control!*

Comment: So I should do like this:
Reader: read the UID, then compute with known Kmaster to provide Ktag, after that, using that Ktag to authenticate with Ultralight C. If authenticated => provide the access. 
Ultralight C: write my own Kmaster(shared with reader) into the tag, then protect all info not to be read by other readers. 
Am I understanding correctly? 
Question about 3DES: so what is 3DES function in the tag? Does it just provide us slots to store enough 3 Keys as I understand? And 1 more thing, in the datasheet, we have 16 bytes to store 2 key (8 bytes/each). I am confusing about this now

Comment: Oh, now I raise another question: So how the tag can authenticate with the Ktag we compute, does it have function to find that Ktag automatically?

Comment: Thanks in advanced, you are my savior since I get lost in this for a while :)

Comment: K_tag vs. K_master: No, you would need to do the same key derivation when personalizing the tag (i.e. when initially writing the key to the tag). So each of your tags actually contains a derived key and **not** the master key.

Comment: 3DES is basically a concatenation of three single DES operations: ENC_3DES(x) = ENC_DES(DEC_DES(ENC_DES(x, K_1), K_2), K_3). (For 3DES decryption, DES encrypt and decrypt operations are the other way round.) There are two versions (one less secure and one more secure): 2-key 3DES and 3-key 3DES. In 3-key 3DES, K_1 != K_2 != K_3. In 2-key 3DES K_1 != K_2 and K_3 = K_1. Ultralight C uses 2-key 3DES, so the two 64 bit (actually only 56 bit with some parity bits) keys are K_1 and K_2, where K_1 is used for the two DES encryption operations and K_2 is used for the DES decryption operation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply :)
"Moreover, an attacker might be able to authenticate with a legit tag and then intercept any further read commands to return manipulated data"
Do you mean about the method like brute-force to try many different Ktag key to authenticate with our tag?

Comment: Since this is NFC, I am intending to implement the same for the NFC-enabled phone, but the phone does not have its unique UID, can you give me some advises?

Comment: You mean that the phone replaces the tag or that the phone is used to verify the tag?

Comment: No, with that statement I meant that you should not trust any data that you read from a supposedly genuine tag even after authentication.

Comment: I'm still not understanding fully what you mention :) And I thought that the range of the NFC is very small (around 4 to 10cm) so that the interception chance is small too, right? Do you have any suggestion on how to implement the access control?

Comment: Yeah, the phone replaces the tag. I mean that we can use the phone to access :)

Comment: Uhm, that's not that easy. Depending on the phone model and operating system I would suggest that you either look into host card emulation (software cand emulation), on implementing a peer-to-peer (+ LLCP + SNEP) protocol stack or on implementing inverse reader mode (if your NFC reader shield uses a PN532, then I would say that's the easiest option). However, that discussion is far beyond the initial question now.

Comment: With an attacker I rather thought about an attacker that owns a legitimate access token. Now if the token (in its data memory) encodes permissions (e.g. you have two doors and both use the same master key to derive the tag keys, and the data memory contains flags that indicate to the reader which of the two doors it is supposed to unlock), then an attacker could perform the authentication step with the genuine tag and redirect all further communication to a tag that contains the proper flags to unlock whatever door they want (even if the genuine tag did not contain those permission flags).

Comment: I intend to implement this into the immobilizer system (to drive one motorbike), so we can use many genuine tags, but open or drive only one system (one motorbike). Then, I don't think that further accessing to drive many others (e.g. 2 doors as your examples) will be the problem.

Comment: About the phone implementation: yes, my shield uses PN532, so how can I implement it? since it will be the next step in my progress after finishing with the tag.

Comment: As I wrote before using a phone is far beyond your initial question. I already gave you some useful search terms to get started with that.

Comment: so about my implementation to drive one motorbike as I mentioned, do you think that the security is ok? Can someone access the system? Can we implement something that will be generated each time there is communication between between card reader and tags so that the information is only at that moment? For example, create some random challenge and receive the corresponding respond

Comment: Hi, about the phone, can you give me a quick response which method to emulate card when I use phone such as Nexus 5 with Android Kitkat 4.4, or using tablet Nexus 7 with Android Kitkat 4.4

Comment: and for phone supporting secure elements, which method I will use?

Comment: hi, i'm not so clear about the 3DES authentication, as you said that I need to derive Ktag, so this Ktag is deriving using 3DES or not? And if this is derving using 3DES, where I store the Ktag on the Ultralight C, from 0x2C to 0x2F where is the storage of the key? and what is the support of 3DES on Ultralight C, is it the ability to store Ktag or it has the hardware/engine to encrypt/decrypt Ktag or Kmaster. I am a little confusing

Comment: Android 4.4: A search for "Host Card Emulation" should give you a start.

Comment: Secure Element: Unless that secure element is yours (which is typically not the case for embedded secure elements and -- unless you are a mobile network operator -- not for the SIM card/UICC either) you can't use that due to the lack of the ability to install your application onto it.

Comment: Deriving Ktag: Read [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) for a starter. You would typically use a KDF based on some current cryptographic hash function.

Comment: 3DES authentication to Ultralight C: Grab full Ultralight C datasheet from the vendor (NXP's). Note that this might require an NDA.

Comment: Is 3DES a KDF? and each specific Ktag will be written into each corresponding tag right?

Comment: 3DES alone is not really suitable as KDF (Google for KDFs and you should find a couple of suitable ones!) The second part is correct, each Ktag must be written to the key area of the tag that it corresponds to during the personalization step.

Comment: Hi,For this implementation I still have one thing confused which is we use 3des on the reader to create Ktag and then use that key for authenticating, so where the decryption of 3des will be implemented?

Comment: And if someone tries to clone the tag, they can clone the UID then listen to the communication to get the Ktag and write it into the cloned tag, then they have the exact tag as the real tag, how can we prevent that happening?

Comment: If you use 3DES to generate Ktag, then you obviously didn't Google for KDFs as I suggested (otherwise you would obviously have chosen some form of one-way hash function). As you don't actually send Ktag to the tag during authentication, an attacker can't easily extract that key from that communication.

Comment: I have searched for KDF, but I'm still confused. In my mind, KDF or 3DES both are used to create a complex key from simpler keys. Either way, we will get a complex Ktag, and we use that Ktag to write into authentication key of the tag.
So, even how complex the Ktag is, when we communicate to authenticate, it is the real Ktag, and if someone try to fake the UID of the tag, then it can listen to the corresponding Ktag from the reader, and they can get that Ktag even don't know how to generate it. Finally, they fake the tag completely. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @BaoDoan Yes, you are missing the principle of password authenticated key agreement.

Comment: Can you explain more, since the full documentation for Mifare Ultralight C needs NDA, it is not easy to get one so I misunderstand some points

Comment: Hi, can you explain shortly the communication between two devices? I have searched around for a while but cannot understand what I am missing :(